# store double pointer address and retrieve its value

Tags: c++, c, pointers

I am trying to store the memory address in a double pointer and cout the value at that memory address but getting errors.

below is the code i am trying to compile:

```
struct doubleValue{
    double a;
};

int main(){
    doubleValue *DBL = new doubleValue;
    DBL->a=15;
    // now I want to store the address of DBL->a in a double pointer and print out the value of double pointer.
    double &doubelPtr = &DBL->a;
    cout<< *doubelPtr; // this value should be 15
}
```

If I run the above code then I get a compiler error "error: invalid initialization of non-const reference of type 'double&' from an rvalue of type 'double*'
     double &doubelPtr = &DBL->a;
                               ^"

Can somebody help me to correct this code? Thanks!

Comment: Learn the difference between the `reference operator` (`&`) and the `address-of operator` (also `&`).  They are not the same thing, but you used both in your sample program.

Comment: Stop (!) using pointers - just use instances (here it is a simple double)

Answer (score 2):

You are erroneously using the `reference` operator here:

```
 double &doubelPtr = &DBL->a;
```

You should just declare a pointer and assign the address to it.

```
 double *doubelPtr = &DBL->a;
```

The above uses the `address-of` operator.  I know it's confusing that both operators (reference and address) use the same symbol `&`, but that's how it is.

However, I'm curious as to why you need to do this?  Is it because you're calling a function that requires a pointer to `double`?  If so, there is no need to do the roundabout way of declaring a pointer to double and assigning to it.  Just pass the address of the double to the function.

Comment: I figured it out. The correct code is:
<code>
double &doublePtr = DBL->a;
cout<<*doublePtr;
</code>

Answer (score 0):

double &doubelPtr should be double *doubelPtr

Answer (score 0):

This is a case of reference vs. pointer;

```
 double &doublePtr
```

is a reference, not an address; try doing this with

```
 double *doublePtr
```